# getdocuments function not stopping

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I'm trying to get data from firestore using this functionL

```
static func getData() -> [Post]{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var posts = [Post]()
    db.collection("Posts").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error retreiving snapshots \(error!)")
            return
        }
        
        for document in snapshot.documents{
            posts.append(Post(t: document.data()["title"] as? String ?? "", a: document.data()["author"] as? String ?? "", pm: document.data()["priceMax"] as? Double ?? 0.0, c: document.data()["content"] as? String ?? ""))
            print("New Post... ")
            print(document.data())
            print(posts.count)
            print(posts[0].title)
            }
        return
    }
    print("test")
    return posts
}
```

and from the print statements I can tell that it gets the data, but the function never ends. print("test") never runs, and thus the posts are never returned. How can I change this so that it returns the data?

Comment: Look up asynchronous functions. The test print and the `return posts` run before the other two print statements. You need a completion handler.

Comment: I looked it up but I still can't figure out how to get the return to wait until getdocuments finishes. I added "let group = DispatchGroup()     group.wait()" to before getdocuments, "group.leave()" in getdocuments, and "group.wait()" before the return but now it crashes.

Comment: What is the minimum macOS or iOS version your app supports? Depending on your answer you will need to either implement a completion handler or declare this function `async`.

Comment: I'm using the newest version of swift, other than that I don't know how to tell what version of iOS it is for. I just want to make the return wait until getdocuments finishes.

Comment: You shouldn't make it wait. It will freeze the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting data from Firestore is an asynchronous call. Try this out:

```
func getData(completion: @escaping([Post], Error?) -> Void) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var posts = [Post]()
        db.collection("Posts").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error retreiving snapshots \(error!)")
                completion(posts, error)
            }
            
            for document in snapshot.documents{
                posts.append(Post(t: document.data()["title"] as? String ?? "", a: document.data()["author"] as? String ?? "", pm: document.data()["priceMax"] as? Double ?? 0.0, c: document.data()["content"] as? String ?? ""))
                print("New Post... ")
                print(document.data())
                print(posts.count)
                print(posts[0].title)
                }
            completion(posts, error)
        }
    }
```

Then call the function like this:

```
getData { posts, error in
     print("Posts: \(posts)")
}
```